# Changing legend labels to what I want

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to change my the labels in plot's legend to say "yearling" and "adult" not "1" and "-1". I first run this code to make this plot:

```
cols <- c("dodgerblue", "goldenrod") #designate colors

density_age_plot <- plot_model(density_model, type = "pred", 
                               terms = c("density_std", "ageclass_std"), 
                               color = cols, show.data = TRUE, jitter = 0.1,
                               axis.title = c("Density", "Proportional Mass Gain"), 
                               title = "Density*Age Class", alpha = 0) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(color = "Age Class") + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This is the graph it makes

[image: This is the graph it makes]

I then try `density_age_plot + scale_color_discrete(labels = c("yearling", "adult"))` but I get this error:
*Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale*

Can anyone help me? ggplot2 is NOT my thing! Thanks!

Comment: what do the data look like - may be easiest to change these so the factor levels are yearling and adult

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

OP, you can probably use `scale_color_manual()`.  Here's a reprex, since I don't have your data.  You pass a vector to the `values=` argument to control the color and a vector to the `labels=` argument to control the labelling.  If you supply a named vector, you can explicitly specify which `value` (color) or `label` is associated with each factor.  Otherwise, it will default to either the levels of the factor or order your items alphanumerically.

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, category = rep(c(1,-1), 5))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=factor(category))) + geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values=c('1'='blue','-1'='red'),
    labels=c('1'="positive",'-1'="negative"))
```

[image]

Note that if you have numbers as factor levels, you would have to refer to them with the backtick syntax (since names cannot be numbers), but if it is a factor, quotes work fine.

Without `scale_color_manual()`, it looks like this:

[image]